# How To create Jsp Ajax Auto complete box

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp

i want to display the list of words when i type the first letter of the word in textbox. i am using jsp design the form.
i tried  same code.it is displaying the data.
but how can i click and select a specific data from the list. i want to select the data in textbox when i click on the items coming after search please short out my problems

Thanks in advance

autocomplete.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showData(value){ 

xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
var url="auto.jsp";
url=url+"?name="+value;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
}
function stateChanged() { 
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
    var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML= showdata;
    } 
}
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
var xmlHttp=null;
try {
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
catch (e) {
 try  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
 catch (e)  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 }
return xmlHttp;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="employee">
<input  type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="showData(this.value);"><br>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

auto.jsp

```
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
    <%

    String name = request.getParameter("name").toString();
    String buffer="<div>";  
    try{
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
               Statement st=con.createStatement();
               ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from users where uname like '"+name+"%'");
    while(rs.next())
    {
      buffer=buffer+rs.getString("uname")+"<br>";
}
buffer=buffer+"</div>";  
response.getWriter().println(buffer);
}
    catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
    %>
```

Comment: i will prefer to use jquery autocomplete [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: For your purpose, you can use some already available jquery plugins like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)